# How to close a modal with a handleClick, outside of the modal?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux

Actually, I use `isAvatarUserMenuOpen` prop into the `UserDataPresentation` class, to know if the modal is opened or not. I use this state to generate a condition that affect the onClick to open and close the modal. But i need to close this modal with any click made outside this modal, actually it only closes in the same button that open it.

I have been doing a handleClick, that add a listener when the modal is opened, and when i click outside the modal, it shows an alert "close de modal!". I need to remove this alert, and find a way to close the modal, just as the onclick that open and close the modal do.

```
export class UserDataPresentation extends React.Component<Props> {
  node: any
  componentWillMount() {
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', this.handleClick, false)
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener('mousedown', this.handleClick, false)
  }

  handleClick = (e: { target: any }) => {
    if (!this.node.contains(e.target)) {
      alert('close de modal!')
      return
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { openMenuUserModal, closeMenuUserModal, isAvatarUserMenuOpen } = this.props
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div className="user-data-container" ref={isAvatarUserMenuOpen ? (node) => (this.node = node) : null}>
          <div className="text">
            <p>Wolfgang Amadeus</p>
          </div>
          <div className="avatar">
            <img src={avatarPhoto} />
          </div>
          <a href="#" onClick={isAvatarUserMenuOpen ? closeMenuUserModal : openMenuUserModal}>
            <div className="svg2">
              <SVG src={downArrow} cacheGetRequests={true} />
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: `componentWillMount` is deprecated, use `componentDidMount` instead

Comment: Or if it's a new project, just switch to a newer version of react and start using stateless component, contextApi and Hooks (Best combo ever, even Nintendo can't do that). Also, you could use something like Material-ui or Ant Design for react, they provide you everything you need :)

Comment: thank you @HermitCrab, i did the change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to call `this.props.closeMenuUserModal()` in your handleClick function.

Comment: thank you!! i knew i just needed something simple left, but i am pretty new in react and i still need some tips and help ahahahaha. Thank you bro, is working good.

Answer (score 1):

I come across this problem quite often and always do the following.

I mix css positioning and react hooks to create a modal. the overlayer div covers the whole div container so when you click any where in the container apart from the modal, the modal dissapears. z-index:1 on #modal makes sure the modal is stacked above the overlayer.

```js
const Modal = () => {
  const [modal, setModal] = React.useState(false);
  return (
    <div id='container'>
      <button onClick={() => setModal(true)}>toggle modal</button>
      {modal && <div id='overlayer' onClick={() => setModal(false)}></div>}
      {modal && <div id='modal'>modal</div>}
      
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Modal/>, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```css
#container{ 
  position: relative;
  height: 200px; width:200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
 }
#container * {position: absolute;}

#overlayer{ 
  height: 100%; width:100%;
 }
#modal{ 
background: blue;
 height: 30%; width:30%;
 top: 12%; z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```